# Is it true that power supply design is difficult when input voltage range is wider?

Tags: power-supply, power, switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, buck

During power supply (buck converter) testing, I had seen the lowest efficiency values corresponding to highest input voltage. I thought if the design meets this worst case scenario, it should be ok no matter how low the input voltage swings (within the max duty ratio limitation, if any).

But when I was listening to an industry expert (general talk on SMPSs, not specific to bucks), he was mentioning if the duty ratio swing is higher, the design will be large and expensive. It is better to limit the duty cycle variations.

Why is it so?

Comment: Yes, that's true.  Both minimum and maximum input voltage put constraints on the design.  Supporting both very low and very high voltages is hard.

Comment: Ok. Can you please let me know what are the additional parameters which will have impact? Clearly efficiency is favoring lower input volatge for buck at least.

Comment: Lowest efficiency for **absolutely any power supply ever made or will be made** is when the load is zero watts. Efficiency cannot be anything else other than 0.000000000%. I think you need to clarify what you are saying. You then follow that paragraph with the industry expert remark and there is no obvious correlation with the previous (and incorrect 1st paragraph on efficiency).

Comment: @Andyakka: Edited the question

Comment: Yes, I see that. I'm still unsure how a wider duty cycle swing equates to `the design will be large and expensive`. Like yesterday's question, I cannot make answers to questions that assert things that are either not clear or seem wrong.

Comment: What was the industry expert referring to when he said "duty ratio swing," or "duty cycle swing"?  Was he talking about a variable load on the output?  Or was he talking about the switching duty cycle of the SMPS itself?  Or something else?

Comment: @Steve: It was about duty cycle swing. Load power remains constant.

Comment: For many of our SMPSs, the worst case efficiencies tend to be at the low end of the input voltage range and the max load on the outputs.  This is probably because under these conditions the duty cycle of the switchers is highest (transistors are turned on the longest) and thus dissipating more power.